# SSRS Switch with And Expression need help , the second condition is not true

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I need a help on the below `Expression`, I've

```
column A - Date, 

Column B-  Yes/No , 

Column C - Date.
```

**Condition**

If `Column B` = Yes and `Column A` has a Date then text box in ***Grey**

If `Column A` don't have Date, then check if `Column C` has date

then if `Column C` date > `Today` and `Column  B` = No text box ***Green***

If `Column C` date < `Today` and `Column B` = No text box ***Red***

Also if there are no entries in any of the column then No color,

I tried to put ISNOTHING(For all 3 columns) with And Operator before switch statement

Comment: I've observed that you have edited your question and that's why I've also updated my answer. Can you please try out with my answer? Hope it would be helpful to you

Comment: I tried it, since Column B is the Checkbox value and it returns Bit 0/1 hence i just changed = 1 instead of yes or no. But the situation is when i dont have a date in column A or column C  and Column B is unchecked   , also Column C date has to change the color based on Today date and Column b has to be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Add your conditions as an expression in the font/color property of the required cell.

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields![Column B].Value = "Yes" AND IsNothing(Fields![Column A].Value), "White",
    IsNothing(Fields![Column A].Value) and Fields![Column C].Value > Today() and Fields![Column B].Value = "", "Red",
    Fields![Column C].Value > Today() and Fields![Column B].Value = "Yes", "Gray",
    Fields![Column C].Value < Today(), "Green"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it could not be the same what I'm providing you but you should try this,

```
=
SWITCH
(
    CStr(Fields!ColumnB.Value) = "Yes" AND NOT(IsNothing(CDate(Fields!ColumnA.Value))), "Grey",
    IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ColumnA.Value),IIF(NOT(IsNothing(Fields!ColumnC.Value)),IIF(CDate(Fields!ColumnC.Value) > Today() AND Fields!ColumnB.Value="","")),"Green")
    CDate(Fields!ColumnC.Value) > Today() AND Fields!ColumnB.Value="Yes","Red"
    IsNothing(Fields!ColumnA.Value) AND IsNothing(Fields!ColumnB.Value) AND IsNothing(Fields!ColumnC.Value), ""
)
```

Also, if above doesn't work then try using separated IIF Statements. It would be more easy.

Comment: I tried it, since Column B is the Checkbox value and it returns Bit 0/1 hence i just changed = 1 instead of yes or no. But the situation is when i dont have a date in column A or column C and Column B is unchecked , also Column C date has to change the color based on Today date and Column b has to be unchecked

Comment: sorry I'm not getting you, you have mentioned in above comment that `But the situation is when i don't have a date in column A or column C and Column B is unchecked ` - so in this case what should be the color? can you please elaborate...

Comment: I have these cases , If column A and Column B and Column c do not have any value - No color , If there is a date in Column A and if Column B is Checked = "Grey color", If column A do not have any value , we check if Column C has date, if there is a date we check whether that date is > Today ="Green", if column c date < Today ="Red", so when we check for column C , column B has to be unchecked.